# Find HTML element's static position

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, wkwebview

Forgive me if my question seems trivial, but I'm a noob to web programming.

The use case I have is the following: I'm displaying a webpage in my mobile app through [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview?language=objc) and need to find the exact coordinates of an element on the webpage once the webpage finishes loading. I plan on having a floating button appear if the element is visible by listening to [scrollViewDidScroll](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll?language=objc) and comparing that with the element's coordinates.

I've done so by [injecting the following JavaScript into the WebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript?language=objc):

```
function f() {  
    var targetElement = document.getElementById("target_element");
    return targetElement.offsetTop;
}

if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    f();
}
```

I inject this and retrieve the y-coordinates from the top of the document [when the WebView finishes loading](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview?language=objc), but I've noticed that this value will sometimes change.

Is there a way to retrieve the static coordinates of the target element just once or do I need to retrieve the most up-to-date coordinates whenever `scrollViewDidScroll` is called? Also, when does `offsetTop` change?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Comment: A friendly reminder , WKWebView APIS will be deprecated by apple in the following months